# Uso de parámetros en consulta SQL nativa

Tags: sql-server, powerquery

Necesito automatizar desde power query una consulta nativa desde SQL server que se alimenta desde Sap B1, la cual tiene un parámetro de fecha para filtrarla. Les comparto parte de la query ya que es demasiado extensa:

```
DECLARE @cont INT 
DECLARE @FECHAHASTA DATETIME
SET @cont = (SELECT TOP 1 T9.TransId FROM [dbo].[JDT1] T9 WHERE T9.RefDate <='[%0]')

SET @FECHAHASTA = '[%0]'

SELECT T0.CardCode, 
        T0.CardName,  
        CASE WHEN T3.DebHab = 'D' THEN Sum(T1.Debit-T1.Credit-T3.ReconSum) 
             WHEN T3.DebHab = 'C' THEN Sum(T1.Debit-T1.Credit+T3.ReconSum) 
             ELSE Sum(T1.Debit-T1.Credit) END 'Saldo', 
        ....
```

Lo que está `[%0]`, es el parámetro de fecha que llama la query. ¿Cómo podría automatizarla desde power query?

Answer (score 1):

logre deifrar mi propia duda:
let
Origen = Sql.Database("miservidor","base",
[Query="DECLARE @cont INT#(lf)
DECLARE @FECHAHASTA DATETIME#(lf)#(lf)
SET @cont =
(SELECT TOP 1 T9.TransId FROM [dbo].[JDT1] T9
WHERE T9.RefDate <=CONVERT(Date,'"&Text.From(Origendinamico)&"'))
#(lf)SET @FECHAHASTA = CONVERT(Date,'"&Text.From(Origendinamico)&"')